# Sorting large amount of strings and grouping

Tags: algorithm, sorting, collections, grouping

I'm trying to find a set of unique strings and break it up into disjoint groups by criterium: if two strings have coincidence at 1 or more columns, it belongs to one group.

For example

```
111;123;222
200;123;100
300;;100
```

All of them are belong to one group, cause of overlap at:

- first string with second by "123" value
- second string with third by "100" value

After getting these groups, I need to save them to a text file.
I got 60 MB file with strings, which should be sorted.(time limit: 30 sec)

I think. First, the best way is to divide strings into columns, and then try to find any coincidence, but I'm not sure at all.

Please, help me to find the solution.

For now, I have this code; it works about 2.5-3 sec:

```
// getting from file
        File file = new File(path);
        InputStream inputFS = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS));
        List<String> inputList = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
        br.close();

        List<String> firstValues = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> secondValues = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> thirdValues = new ArrayList<>();

        // extracting distinct values and splitting
        final String qq = "\"";


        inputList.stream()
                .map(s -> s.split(";"))
                .forEach(strings -> {
                    firstValues.add(strings.length > 0 ? strings[0].replaceAll(qq, "") : null);
                    secondValues.add(strings.length > 1 ? strings[1].replaceAll(qq, "") : null);
                    thirdValues.add(strings.length > 2 ? strings[2].replaceAll(qq, "") : null);
                });

// todo: add to maps by the row and then find groups
```

Comment: When posting code, please indicate what language you're using and the problem you're having with the code.

Comment: Although [the disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) seems like it would help with solving this problem.